# Comma operator with static_assert()

Tags: c++, runtime, static-assert

When trying to evaluate comma operator with `static_assert` as an argument compilation fails

```
void fvoid() {}

int main() {
    int a = (1, 2); // a=2
    int b = (fvoid(), 3); // b=3

    int d = ( , 5);
    //        ^
    // error: expected primary-expression before ',' token. OK

    int c = (static_assert(true), 4);
    //       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // error: expected primary-expression before 'static_assert'. Why?
}
```

It looks like that `static_assert()` doesn't even resolve to `void` after compiling. I didn't manage to find anything regarding this in standard. Is there a way to use it with comma operator or use it in line with other expression (without semicolon)?

Comment: Just curious: why would you want to use it with the comma operator?

Comment: @Rakete1111 in some condition macro that usually returns a value should fail static assert, but still it needs to be resolvable to a value so compiler doesn't generate redundant errors.

Comment: Makes sense, and you might want to consider changing the title, as it is another question altogether that had nothing to do with your actual question

Comment: Another case that comes to mind, @Rakete1111, is within a constructor's member initialiser list.  It would be useful to be able to use a construct such as, e.g., `constexpr Type(Param p) : member{static_assert(condition, "Something went wrong."), p} {}`.

Comment: @JustinTime You can put that in the body though.

Comment: You usually can, yes, @Rakete1111.  The main use case I can see for such a construct is if `member`'s construction could fail based on the parameters, and you want to provide a more relevant error message while still initialising `member` in the initialiser list.  Probably not the _most_ common thing, but it can come up sometimes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is not. The language grammar requires a semicolon at the end of the static assert *declaration*.

> N4140 §7 [dcl.dcl]/1
>
> *static_assert-declaration*:
>
> ​ ​ ​ ​`static_assert (` *constant-expression* , *string-literal* `)` ;

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to use it with comma operator or use it in line with other expression (without semicolon)?

As already mentioned in other answers, you cannot avoid using a semicolon when dealing with a `static_assert`.
Anyway, you can wrap it in a lambda as it follows and still use it somehow with the comma operator:

```
int main() {
    int c = ([]{ static_assert(true, "!"); }(), 4);
}
```

Likely you want to test something more elaborated than `true`.
In this case, you have to work around the (let me say) *limitations* of the current lambda definition (for which neither capturing nor passing as an argument the boolean value works).
A function template with a non-type template argument can do the job. As an example:

```
template<bool b>
void f() {
    int c = ([](){ static_assert(b, "!"); }(), 4);
    // ...
}
```

Once optimized, the resultant code that uses a lambda does not differ that much (you can easily check it on [godbolt](http://godbolt.org) by using these minimal examples).

Comment: This code is also using fold expressions for brevity.

`template<bool ...b>
void f() {
    ([](){ static_assert(b, "!"); }(), ...);
}`

Parameter pack expansion seems to not work in gcc and work in clang and msvc, am I relying on undefined behavior or something like that or is it just a bug on gcc?

Comment: @PedroDavid It looks like a bug of GCC actually. It's worth it opening an issue if it doesn't exist. Anyway, I'd do this in C++17: `static_assert((b && ...), "!");`. [It works fine also with GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/x3A2RZ5lRvceLezO). No need to wrap it in a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap it in a block:

```
int c = ({ static_assert(true); }, 4);
```

Comment: This fails to compile on GCC (and clang): *"error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token"* ([demo](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/PzOvRCE3MTNPQ1OhmksBCEACyQq2ChrVCsUliSWZyfGJxcWpRSUaJUWlqZrWCrU6Ciaa1ly1//8DAA)).